# python parse variable inside print or variable

Tags: python, fabric

trying to parse variable inside print statement.

```
client = fabric.operations.prompt("Enter client's email address:")
cmd = 'mysql -u %s -p%s -e "UPDATE users SET email = ' %(env.user, dbpasswd) + '"%client"' + ' WHERE id = 1" %s' %account
print cmd
```

result:

```
mysql -u root -password -e "UPDATE users SET email = %client WHERE id = 1" demo
```

desired result:

```
mysql -u root -password -e "UPDATE users SET email = 'abc@xyz.com' WHERE id = 1" demo
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm surprised nobody has mentioned the new string formatting options:

```
cmd = 'mysql -u {user} -p{passwd} -d "UPDATE users SET email = {email} WHERE id = 1" {account}'.format(user=env.user, passwd=dbpasswd, email=client, account=account)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
cmd = 'mysql -u %s -p %s -e "UPDATE users SET email = ' %(env.user, dbpasswd) + "'%s'" % client + ' WHERE id = 1" %s' % account
```

That should fix it. You needed to replace `%client` by the value of `client`.